# Abelianization of GL_n

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $k$ is a field.

1. How to prove that the abelianization of $GL_2(k)$ is $GL_1(k)$ ?
2. Ditto for $GL_n(k)$.
3. Can we say the same thing, were we to replace $k$ with $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: $\det$ is a homomorphism from $GL_n(R)\rightarrow k^*=GL_1(R)$ for any commutative ring $R$. To see that it is really an isomorphism we have to show that every matrix with determinant $1$ can be written as a product of commutators. So we have to find a generating system for $SL_n(k)$ and show that each of them is a commutator. This should be possible for Euclidean rings. You might want to read the wikipedia article about algebraic K-theory.

Comment: 3. No, we cannot say this for $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$. It is not true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any field $k$, the abelianization of $GL_n(k)$ is $k^{\ast}$ except for $n=2$ and $k=\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{F}_3$. I think this is in Lang's *Algebra*, [Chapter XIII](http://books.google.com/books?id=Fge-BwqhqIYC&lpg=PP1&dq=algebra%20lang&pg=PA536#v=onepage&q&f=false) sections 8 and 9. (I say I think because I am relying on google books here, and some key pages are missing.)

**EDIT:** I just looked back at this old answer, and the abelianization of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ is $\mathbb{F}_3^{\times}$ as well, so $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$ is the only counterexample. I think that what I was thinking when I wrote this is that the abelianization of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ in nontrivial.

Comment: But if $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is its own commutator, we can reduce modulo $2$ and $3$ and conclude the same for $F_2$ and $F_3$, no?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer that this statement is for fields. As you say, if we knew that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ was its own commutator, then it would follow that $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ was for every $p$; so this shows that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is NOT its own commutator.

Answer (score -1):

As HenrikRueping points out, the determinant map $\det:\textrm{GL}_n(k) \longrightarrow k^\ast$ factors through the abelianization $\textrm{GL}_n(k)_{ab}$ of $\textrm{GL}_n(k)$. The induced morphism $\textrm{GL}_n(k)_{ab} \longrightarrow k^\ast$ can be shown to be an isomorphism as follows. It's clearly surjective. Thus, we have to show injectivity. To do so, you have to show that each element of $\textrm{SL}_n(k)$ is a commutator.

For $n=2$, I thought one could generate $\textrm{SL}_2(k)$ with the two matrices

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1& 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$$

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0& 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$

So if you just show that these are commutators you're done, right?

Jim points out that these matrices do not generate $\textrm{SL}_2(k)$ but $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: what are the two standard generators of sl_2?

Comment: Whoops I mixed up some things. I'll edit my answer (which is no longer an answer). Sorry.

Comment: These are generators for $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$, not $k$.